# #Develop installer- This setup requires the .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 to be installed

Tags: .net, sharpdevelop

I'm trying to install the latest version of #Develop but am getting the message

This setup requires the .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 to be installed

I'm running Windows 7, and I've tried running the installer for .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 plus the installer for the Windows 7 SDK.

The installer just says to use the Control Panel to turn Windows Features on and off to configure .NET Framework 3.5 SP1

Anyone got any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used Control Panel to disable the 3.5 features, reinstalled 3.5 sp1 and then used Control Panel to re-enable them.

I checked the registry value that Matt suggested, and it was indeed 1, without any editing required.

Ran the installer and it installed successfully.

I even have version 2.2 installed and both seem to work.

Answer (score 3):

As the message says, install [.net3.5 **SP1**](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=AB99342F-5D1A-413D-8319-81DA479AB0D7&displaylang=en)

Comment: I've run the installer for the .NET Framework SP1 (sorry for forgetting to add the 'sp1' part to my original post) and the installer for the framework sp1 seems to complete successfully.

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be a problem identifying whether .NET 3.5 SP1 is installed on Windows 7.

SharpDevelop's installer checks the following registry key to ensure .NET 3.5 SP 1 is installed:

Key="HKLM\Software\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v3.5"

Name="SP"

The value of this registry entry needs to be 1. Create this registry entry if it does not exist and SharpDevelop should install successfully.